# What does 'cb' in cb_kwargs stand for?

Tags: python

What does *cb* in *cb_kwargs* (one entry in parameter list of python) stand for?

I believe *kwargs* means keyword arguments. But I don’t have no idea about *cb*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cb_kwargs` is not a python reserved keyword or builtin function, so it can mean anything depending on context.

However, I believe that the typical use is as a dictionary of keyword, value pairs that is meant to be passed to a callback function at some time, for example:

```
cb_kwargs = {'timeout':22, 'verbose':False}
```

Then some function `callback` might later be called as

```
callback(**cb_kwargs)
```

which for this particular dictionary would be equivalent to calling it as:

```
callback(timeout=22, verbose=False)
```

Answer (score 3):

Callback, I believe. Not necessary though.